# Can I get the ALTRUIST ACOLYTE Achievement after I complete all the Stranger encounter sub-missions?

Tags: achievements, grand-theft-auto-v

Can I still get the Altruist Acolyte achievement after I complete all the Stranger encounter sub-missions?

To get the achievement you are supposed to bring the Stranger randomly encountered at the roadside to the Cult base, but I'm way too much of a good guy. I deliver them to the place they want to go.

Can I replay those missions? If I can't, does it mean I can't get the achievement at all?

Comment: You mean another achievement. The KIFFLOM! achievement is for completing the Epsilon Cult missions. The achievement you mean is Altruist Acolyte.

Comment: ah yes, ALTRUIST ACOLYTE

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can still get the Altruist acolyte achievement even though you would have done all the random encounters. You can take a taxi and take the fares to the Altruist camp.

Comment: Have a +1 just because this sounds like fun :)

Comment: But Trevor tried to drive a taxi ride to the Camp, and nothing happens. Why ?

Comment: This answer got upvotes but I doubt anyone actually tested it. It does not work, you cannot drop taxi fares there.